# Optimized alternative to stashing files in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The jenkins pipeline currently does a build and deploy, stashes some files, unstashes them and runs end to end tests on these files as so:

```
// build and deploy code 
stash([
    name: 'end-to-end-tests',
    includes: <a bunch of files>
])
unstash('end-to-end-tests')
// code to run tests using npm run test:end-to-end-tests
```

In the interest of speeding up this pipeline, is there a way to get around the stash? I need `end-to-end-tests` in order to run my tests with the appropriate npm command later on, but how can I use this without stashing (if possible)?

Comment: stash/unstash is used when the two operations are performed on separate nodes/workspaces, but you need to reuse files. If you can use the same node/workspace, then you don't need to use stash/unstash. Otherwise, you need to pass the fiule(s) one way or another. Stash is convenient, but you could use an external file/artifact repository (Nexus,Artifactory/NFS/S3/...)

Comment: We examined a lot of alternatives, including checkouts with mirrors, and in our experience stash/unstash has been optimal w.r.t times, bandwidth, and overall management efforts.